# Can we declare a class in two files in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, class

Say some function is defined in one file and another function is defined in another file

In C++ you can do that right

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to create [partial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yfzd5350.aspx) class. That way you may splits the definition of class into two or more files.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Partial classes [msdn link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yfzd5350.aspx).

This means you can do something like this:

```
Partial Public Class partialClass
    Public Sub method1()
    End Sub
End Class
Partial Public Class partialClass
    Public Sub method2()

    End Sub
End Class
```

BTW, this is not the same you can do in C++. In C++, you can separate function declaration from the implementation. In VB, you can separate methods and properties, but you can't declare a function in one partial class and implement it in the another partial class